# Does cloudflare hide the visitors' ip from clientside also?

Tags: ip, visitor-pattern, cloudflare

I have an application stored in a hosting that has Cloudflare's protection. The application in the client's side, from javascript does an ajax request to the page `http://ipinfo.io` and get the ip, location and some information of the visitor. Nevertheless the result is similar to:

```
IP: 141.101.75.82
Hostname: No Hostname
ISP: AS13335 CloudFlare, Inc.
```

Since you will see, the information does not belong to the visitor, the information is of Cloudflare.

Someone knows how this problem can be solved?

Sorry for orthographic failures, regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reply but I've solved it. I disabled this option:

[image]

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It sounds like you were doing something JavaScript or jQuery wise (only things that Rocket Loader would impact).

Comment: @damoncloudflare of course that's why I said I was trying to get the ip from clientside via ajax. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed something like [mod_cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200038166-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-to-my-server-logs-) to restore the original visitor IP? That should work.

Comment: mod_cloudflare es for serverside, my problem was from clientside but as I have said, I've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing, the connecting IP can be found in the 'HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP' header